# Can/Should I add a database in a Docker container?

Tags: python, sql-server, database, docker

I am working on a program that requires a Microsoft SQL server to run, I need some kind of environment that can easily be shared with other developers, naturally docker came in mind.
Can I have an installation of the Microsoft SQL server with my scripts, dependencies, python installation etc. in a docker container? is this something to be avoided? 
Thank you.

Comment: yes of course you can

Comment: Our team does the same and you can easily share it with other developers by uploading it to a private repo on docker hub!